# Running an update before an EF code based migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

When trying a number of scenarios to evaluate code based migrations i noticed that
entity framework will not apply the migration to the database if the database
contains data that cannot be converted automatically or would be truncated (reduced length, string->int, string->datetime...) which of course is a good thing.

Now if i want to run an update script just before the migration for example to change all the date strings into the same format would i put that update directly into the Up() method of the migration or is there a better place?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use code migration (the one which adds all migration code to the `Up` method) and insert `Sql(...)` calls before all that generated migration code.